# Jest + Typescript how do I test a method in the React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm creating .tsx components with Typescript/React. I want to do some unit tests of the methods inside the React component. Say:

```
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component<undefined, SomeComponentState> {

    someMethod = (string: someInput) => {
        return someInput + someInput;
    }
    render () .. // etc
}
```

In a SomeComponent.test.tsx file, how do I import and test the method of `someMethod`, and not the whole component itself?

I've tried:

```
import {someMethod} from "./someComponent";
```

though without luck - it doesn't seem to be invokable, and will throw TS error: "component has no exported member someMethod"

Comment: Unless it's a static method, it makes no sense to test it without instantiating a component

Answer (score 5):

Its a member of the class, so you need an instance to test it. You can't import it directly. If it doesn't need to access to anything else on the instance,
you can extract it as a seperate function and export it.

Alternatively using [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) you could test it with something like this:
    import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

```
it('.....', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />);
    (wrapper.instance() as SomeComponent).someMethod('someValue');
})
```

Comment: I've tried with Enzyme; Doesn't seem to work either. With your method, I get "Property someMethod does not exist on on type Component"

Comment: you might need to tell TS the type eg ```wrapper.instance() as SomeComponent```

Comment: Okay, it works, however the test fails with some obscure error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` hmm ..